# Loop wordpress com diferentes posições de div

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tenho uma categoria de receitas no Wordpress aparecem 2 postagem nela. Gostaria que cada post tivesse uma formatação.

 Ex: Conteúdo para esquerda e imagem a direita e outro post imagem a direita e conteúdo a esquerda mas não sei como fazer isso no loop do wp. Teria como alguém me ajudar?

Comment: Pergunta confusa. O título não parece ter a ver com o corpo da pergunta. Tente melhorar para podemos ajudá-lo

Comment: Obrigado, sou novo aqui caso consiga me ajudar com essa minha situação agradeceria muito :)

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi bem você quer modificar apenas o layout, a forma como é exibido os posts, se for isso mesmo, coloco um exemplo abaixo:

```html
// Função de busca de posts de uma determinada categoria e limitando a quantidade de post's
function get_post_custom($id_categoria, $limite=3)
{
  $additional_loop = new WP_Query("cat=$id_categoria&posts_per_page=$limite");

  $found_posts = $additional_loop->found_posts;

  //Verifica se existem post's nesta categoria
  if (0!=$found_posts) {

    //Usaremos a frente
    $valor = 1;

    while ($additional_loop->have_posts()) : $additional_loop->the_post();

    $permalink = get_permalink();
    
    $category_id = get_cat_ID( 'Últimas notícias' ); //Aqui você insere a categoria que deseja listar

    $category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
    
    //Para alternar o layout crie uma classe css, uma que configura os elementos para a esquerda e outra para  direita
    //Para alterar as classes podemos utilizar um verificador, acima criei uma variável e logo no final do loop eu incremento ela, para saber se o número é impar ou par criei um if, dependendo do resultado ele muda o valor da variável $class
    if($valor % 2 == 1){
      $class = "classeConfigEsquerda";
    } else {
      $class = "classeConfigDireita";
    }
    
    //Exibindo os post's, repare que foi inserida a classe na div
    echo '
    <div class="<?php echo $class; ?>">     
      <div class="news-content">
        <a href="'.$permalink.'" title="'.get_the_title().'">
          <p><strong>'.get_the_title().'</strong></p>
          <span>Ler mais</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>';
    $valor++;
    endwhile;
  }
}
```

Comment: estava tentando algo assim:

Answer (score 0):

```
      <?php
       $i = 0;
//Faz uma consulta dos posts, recebendo o parametro post_type, que pega os 
        posts do tipo cpt
       $post_type = new WP_Query( 'post_type=cpt' );
//Verifica se encontrou posts
if ( $post_type->have_posts() ) :
    //Fz um loop nos posts
    while ( $post_type->have_posts() ) :
        $post_type->the_post();
        //Veirica o resto da divisão de $i por 2
        if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) : ?>
            <div class="post-de-um-jeito" ></div> <?php
        else: ?>
            <div class="post-de-outro-jeito"></div> <?php
        endif;
    endwhile;
endif;
   ?>
```

Mas ai gostaria que chama-se uma determinada categoria .

Comment: Mas a função que coloquei acima você consegue buscar a categoria que você quiser amigo.

Comment: mas ai como faço para chamar essas duas divs diferentes que eu tenho intercalando uma e outra

Comment: Isso não é uma resposta. Você deveria editar sua pergunta e acrescentar esse trecho.